# Mysql return empty rows if multi where condition with empty value

Tags: php, mysql, database, phpmyadmin, mysql-workbench

I have created the table in the name of folders table 
    It contain Name,FolderId,ParentFolderId 
    When i write a where query its return empty rows

```
Example 1 :
Query :
select * from folders_tbl where parentResourceId='' 

Result : 
As I Expected
```

But I have add some where condition in this it will fail to return expected rows

```
Example 2 : (Issue)
QUERY :
SELECT *  FROM folders_tbl WHERE parentResourceId =  ''
AND serviceId =1
AND userId =1

Result : 
 returned an empty result set

Table Structure 

folderId    bigint(20)  
serviceId   int(11)     
userId  bigint(20)      
folderName  varchar(200)    
resourceId  varchar(500)    
parentResourceId    varchar
createdDate datetime    
modifiedDate    datetime    
Shared  int(11)         
isTrashed   int(11)     
isDeleted   int(11)        

Note : I write a query in phpMyAdmin web UI
```

Comment: Can you share your data? Offhand, it sounds as if MySQL is acting as it's supposed to.

Comment: Do you have NULL value, check for where parentResourceId is NULL

Answer (score 1):

It seems you have records which contains null value. If it is then use

`parentResourceId is null` in where condition